# Supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I guess that the answer should be well known, but I fail to find a reference for it. For any prime $p$, is there a supersingular elliptic curve actually defined over $\mathbb F_p$ ?

In Katz and Mazur's book in the proof of Theorem 2.9.4, the authors show that any supersingular elliptic curve over $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$ can be defined over $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ if $p$ is odd, and over $\mathbb F_{16}$ if $p=2$. But is there at least one of them which actually stems from $\mathbb F_p$ ?

**Edit:** In Li and Oort's book "Moduli of supersingular abelian varieties", at the top of page 9, the authors write "For every $p$ there exists a supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_p$."
Therefore it seems that the answer is affirmative, however they do not offer a justification as to why it is true.

Comment: That’s a good question! At least for $p=2$ mod $3$ or $p=3$ mod $4$ the answer should be yes, due to the CM curves $y^2=x^3+1$ and $y^2=x^3+x$.

Comment: Not only do supersingular elliptic curves exist over $\mathbb{F}_p$, but you can even give an algorithm to compute them: https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6875 or https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/access/item%3A2895327/view

Comment: This follows for Theorem 14.18. in Cox's book Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2$ for $a=0$. See also page 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.12185.pdf.

Comment: [Here is how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpc7F.png) Tate and Shafarevitch, in Tate, Shafarevitch - The rank of elliptic curves – in Collected works of John Tate, part 1" prove the existence of a supersingular EC over $\mathbb F_p$, if $p$ is odd, by invoking [4] : Deuring, Die Typen der Multiplikatorenringe elliptischer Funktionenkörper, 1941.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is always at least one supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbf{F}_p$.

Assume that $p$ is odd. (For $p=2$ take $j=0=1728$).  Let $q \equiv -1 \bmod 4$ be a prime such that $-q$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$ (they exist). Let $F = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-q})$. The class number $h$ of $F$ is odd, and if $H$ is the Hilbert class field of $F$, then $\mathrm{Gal}(H/\mathbf{Q})$ is dihedral, and Frobenius at $p$ is a reflection (since it is non-trivial in the quotient $\mathrm{Gal}(F/\mathbf{Q})$). In particular, if $H^{+} \subset H$ is any subfield of degree $h$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ (all such fields are isomorphic), then there is a (unique as it happens) prime above $p$ in $H^{+}$ of degree one.

Now by the theory of complex multiplication, there exists an elliptic curve $E$ with CM by the ring of integers of $F$ which is defined over a subfield $H^{+}$ of degree $h$. For example, one can take it to have $j$-invariant

$$j = j \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{-q}}{2} \right) \in \mathbf{R},$$

(Since $F(j) = H$ and $j$ is real it follows that $H^{+} = \mathbf{Q}(j)$ has index two in $H$).

By assumption, there is a prime above $p$ in $H^{+}$ of degree one, and reducing $E$ modulo this prime we get an elliptic curve $E/\mathbf{F}_p$. Because $p$ is inert in $F$ this will be supersingular.

An example. If $p=3$, then you could take $q=7, 19, 31, \ldots$. If $q=7$, then

$$j = -3375 \equiv 0 \bmod 3,$$

If $q = 31$ on the other hand (to give an example with $h > 1$) then $j$ is a root of

$$1566028350940383 - 58682638134x + 39491307x^2 + x^3 = 0.$$

There is a unique solution in $\mathbf{Q}_3$ given by

$$j = 3^3 + 3^5 + 2 \cdot 3^6 + 2 \cdot 3^8 + 3^9 + 3^{10} + \ldots $$

and (of course again) $j = 0 \bmod 3$.

Comment: Very nice argument! I was trying something like this but I very clearly wasn’t going about it in the right way. I just had a question: do we use that the class number is odd somewhere in the argument? If so, do you know of a reference for this fact?

Comment: I see. Indeed, $p$ is inert in $K$ so $p$ splits totally in $H$, hence the decomposition group at $p$ of $H/\mathbb{Q}$ has order $2$ and has trivial intersection with $Gal(H/K)$…

Comment: I don't even understand what you mean with "$E$ will have CM". Don't you need to show that some endomorphism is not in $\Bbb{Q} \otimes \Bbb{Z}[\phi_p]$ or that $p \nmid \# E(\Bbb{F}_{p^n})$ ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's very clever. I have an additional question which came to me after you posted this answer. In Li and Oort's book, they state that for an elliptic curve over a field $k$ of characteristic $p$, it may happen that $\mathrm{End}(E)$ has rank $2$ whereas $\mathrm{End}(E\otimes \overline{k})$ has rank $4$, so that the supersingularity of $E$ is visible only after a scalar extension. With $k = \mathbb F_p$, would you know if both cases, that is $\mathrm{End}(E)$ having rank $2$ or $4$ before scalar extension, can happen?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is all very clear and instructive.